# ACCESS Bug when using grouping & sorting for a report

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a form with a included report. This report can be updated with control elements. That works. Now I would like to group the result so that I can calculate sums for the groups. That works, too. However, I now have the problem that changing the control elements does not update the query anymore. The report in the background and the stored source are updated but the changes are not visible. Only when I close the form and open it again, the changes are displayed.

[image: Group function]

I tryed to:

```
Refresh
Recalc
Repaint
Requery
```

Also the Requery for all Reports doesn't work at all

```
With Reports
        ' Iterate over all open reports...
    For Each rpt In Reports
        rpt.Requery
    Next
End With
```

Has anyone a idea how to solve it?

When I use: CommandBars.ExecuteMso "DataRefreshAll"
[image: When I use: CommandBars.ExecuteMso "DataRefreshAll"]

Comment: Is the report displayed on the form or as a report object?

Comment: Did you try refreshing the entire form while it is open? When the report is embedded within the form it essentially functions like a control, so to that extent a complete form refresh may trigger the "control" to reset its data.

Comment: It worked before you set grouping? What do you mean by 'report in the background'? Is the report RecordSource a dynamic parameterized query referencing form controls? Exactly what does not change - the records or the group sums? Try `CommandBars.ExecuteMso "DataRefreshAll"`.

Comment: The report is displayed on the form (like a subform). I tryed to refresh the whole form with formname.refresh.

Comment: Yes, without grouping it works fine. With report in Background I mean the query, which is the basis for the report. The RecordSource is static in the properties field, it doesn't change over time. The values and the sums don't update.